# determinants of 2 matrices with given property

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have two $3\times3$ integer matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=A+B$. I need to find all possibe values of $\det(A-E)$, where $E$ denotes the identity matrix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does B.I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$\bullet\;\;\;\;\;AB=A+B\implies (A-I)(B-I)=I\;,\;\;I:=\text{the unit (identity) matrix)}$$

$$\bullet\;\;\;\;\text{For square matrices $\,X,Y\,$ of the same order, it's true that}\;\;\det(XY)=\det X\cdot\det Y$$

Comment: Sorry..I tried to solve how you said but I still can't figure it out..Can you give me another advice ?

Comment: If $\,(A-I)(B-I)=I\;$ is already clear, then point two tells you that $\,\det(A-I)\,$ is a divisor of $\,1\,$ . If you're working with matrices over a field this means $\,B-I=(A-I)^{-1}\,$ and, in any case, this tells you $\,A-I\,$ is invertible and thus its determinant can only be a unit...

Comment: Thank you for your help..I understand now

Comment: Any time, @EmilGrigore ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that $A=(A+B)-B=AB-B=(A-E)B$.